# Function won't accept less than three arguments

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I'm working with someone else's database connection PHP function that works fine as long as I pass it at least three arguments.  If I pass it two argument, then the apache log says:

`mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given`

I need the function to take a SQL query like so:

`$sql = DatabaseManager::prepare("SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE somevar = %d", $var);`

and prepare it for safe execution.  Can someone help make it accept two arguments?

```
public static function prepare($query = null) { // ( $query, *$args )

    $args = func_get_args();

    array_shift($args);

    // If args were passed as an array (as in vsprintf), move them up
    if ( isset($args[0]) && is_array($args[0]) ){
        $args = $args[0];
    }

    $query = str_replace("'%s'", '%s', $query); // in case someone mistakenly already singlequoted it
    $query = str_replace('"%s"', '%s', $query); // doublequote unquoting
    $query = str_replace('%s', "'%s'", $query); // quote the strings

    for($i=0; $i<count($args); $i++){
        $args[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string($args[$i], self::$currentCon);
    }

    //array_walk($args, array(&$this, 'mysql_real_escape_string'));

    return @vsprintf($query, $args);
}
```

Thanks a ton!

**EDIT**

As deceze points out, this is about `self::$currentCon)` and means that a database connection is coming back `null`

I've tried this multiple times.  Still curious about why this works:

```
$sql = DatabaseManager::prepare("SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE id = ".$somevar);
```

but this fails:

```
$sql = DatabaseManager::prepare("SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE somevar = %d", $var);
```

How would that affect `self::$currentCon)`?

Comment: Please provide an example of how you'd call this function with only one argument. It seems that the change you're looking for doesn't fit the purpose of the function.

Comment: @Jeff, true that.  Many apologies for the poor phrasing.  I mean one extra argument for the SQL query.  I edited my post to clarify.  But so far it will only take three arguments (including the SQL query) or more

Comment: This look suspiciously like you're trying to reinvent the (PDO) wheel. Have you considered using an existing database connection library?

Comment: +1 Amber...that's probably a really good idea--a suggestion that might definitely help someone else on this forum.  Unfortunately, I'm the lost entrepreneur following the lead of the guy who wrote this library :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given

That's a completely different problem than the number of arguments a function accepts. Read it again:

> ***`mysql_real_escape_string()`*** expects parameter 2 ***to be resource***, `null` given

It refers to this line:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($args[$i], self::$currentCon);
```

The second parameter for `mysql_real_escape_string`, i.e. `self::$currentCon`, should be a reference (a *resource*) to an open MySQL connection. In this case though it was `null`.

This means there's some problem with `self::$currentCon`. Either there's a problem in the code that sets `self::$currentCon`, or your database configuration details (username, password, socket, etc.) are wrong and a connection to the database couldn't be established, hence `self::$currentCon` is `null`.

This problem should've been caught much earlier, at the time the database connection was supposed to be established, but the author seems to be a fan of error suppression, so the problem only manifests itself here.

The moral of the story:

- Always read error messages thrice.
- Always give the exact error message when asking a question.
- Don't suppress errors.

:)

Comment: thanks @deceze!  that makes sense and I will follow that lead...  The connection to the database works however if I feed it: $sql = DatabaseManager::prepare("SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE id = ".$somevar); but fails when I feed it $sql = DatabaseManager::prepare("SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE somevar = %d", $var);  Any reason for that?

Comment: @Emile Yes. If you supply no extra `$args`, the `for (...) { ... }` loop isn't run at all, hence the offending `mysql_real_escape_string` is never called. That loop is only run as many times as there are (extra) arguments.

Answer (score 1):

maybe it's just me, i'd write the function like this

```
public static function prepare($query = null,$args = array()) {
    $query = str_replace("'%s'", '%s', $query); // in case someone mistakenly already singlequoted it
    $query = str_replace('"%s"', '%s', $query); // doublequote unquoting
    $query = str_replace('%s', "'%s'", $query); // quote the strings

    foreach($args as $key=>$arg){
        $args[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($arg, self::$currentCon);
    }

    //array_walk($args, array(&$this, 'mysql_real_escape_string'));

    return @vsprintf($query, $args);
}
```

I haven't tested it.. i don't understand why the function is using `func_get_args()` and `array_shift()` and then test if there was or not a second argument.. it seems too complicated, at least for me

Comment: Thanks @pleasedontbelong ... My first steps into PHP so forgive me for the ignorance, but my apache log says "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` when I run the code using your function.  (although you did get rid of the last error message :)  Any ideas?

Comment: well.. reading the other answers, and the apache log, i think this was not the problem so @deceze might be right. But just as a reference, if you use the function as i posted here, you would have to call the function in a different way.. something like this prepare("SELECT...", array($var1,$var2,...));... anyway.. use your original code and check the parameters passed to the mysql_real_escape_string() function

Answer (score 0):

Your prepare need a 1 parameter($query);

```
DatabaseManager::prepare("SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE somevar = %d", $var);
```

- in this code you give 2 parameters to function.

Comment: very good point @Alexander...Thanks for the help in clarifying my question.  I mean that it won't take 1 extra parameter.  So including the SQL query, it won't take anything less than 3 parameters.  I edited my question to clarify.